# Comparing 2 lists/Tables in Javascript using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 tables, say Table 1 and Table 2.

Table 1 has 2 columns:

```
Col B  |   Col C

row 11  | row 12 
row 21  | row 22 
row 31  | row 32
```

Table 2 also has 2 columns:

```
Col B  |   Col C

row 21  | row 22 
row 21  | row 01 
row 11  | row 12
```

I want to compare Table 1 with Table 2 and to do few things; compare both tables and make sure all the missing values of table 1 are added to Table 2 in the same order.

**Expected result**

```
Col B  |   Col C

row 11  | row 12
row 21  | row 22 
row 31  | row 32
row 21  | row 01
```

I tried implementing using foreach loop on both tables, assuming the tables from a JSON structure but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. What would be the best way to achieve the above results? Thanks

Sample List:

```
{
    "defaultValue": [{
        "CellValues": [{
            "defaultValue": "row 11"
        }, {
            "defaultValue": "row 12"
        }]
    }, {
        "CellValues": [{
            "defaultValue": "row 21"
        }, {
            "defaultValue": "row 22"
        }]
    },{
        "CellValues": [{
            "defaultValue": "row 31"
        }, {
            "defaultValue": "row 32"
        }]
    }]
}    

$.each(Table1, function (Table1RowIndex, Table1Rowvalue) {
    $.each(Table1Rowvalue.cells)(), function (Table1CellIndex, Table1Cellvalue) {
        $.each(Table2, function (Table2rowIndex, Table2row) {
            $.each(Table2.cells(), function (Table2cellIndex, Table2cell) {
                //
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just curious, is the complex object/array setup for your tables set in stone? It might be easier to code a solution if you could do something simpler, like this: `[ ["row 11", "row 12"], ["row 21", "row 22"], ["row 31", "row 32"] ]`

Comment: i have simplified and posted here as my JSON itself is complex and not as straight forward as u mentioned !

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do 3 nested loops instead of 4. You do proper nested loops for the rows, but when you loop through the columns for table 1, you just get the corresponding column from table 2 using the index.

It's also a good idea to make a clone of one of the tables to act as your output...changing an array that you are looping through can cause issues.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var t1 = {
  "defaultValue": [
   {"CellValues": [
    { "defaultValue": "row 11" }, 
    { "defaultValue": "row 12" }]
   }, {"CellValues": [
    { "defaultValue": "row 21" }, 
    { "defaultValue": "row 22" }]
   }, { "CellValues": [
    { "defaultValue": "row 31" }, 
    { "defaultValue": "row 32" }] 
   }
  ]
 };

 var t2 = {
  "defaultValue": [
   {"CellValues": [
    { "defaultValue": "row 21" }, 
    { "defaultValue": "row 22" }]
   }, {"CellValues": [
    { "defaultValue": "row 21" }, 
    { "defaultValue": "row 01" }]
   }, { "CellValues": [
    { "defaultValue": "row 11" }, 
    { "defaultValue": "row 12" }] 
   }
  ]
 };

 var out = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t1)); // clone t1 to use as output

 $.each(t2.defaultValue, function(i2, r2) {
  var rowMatch = false;
  $.each(t1.defaultValue, function(i1, r1) {
   var cellMatch = true;
   $.each(r1.CellValues, function(j, c1) {
    var c2 = r2.CellValues[j];
    if(c1.defaultValue!=c2.defaultValue) {
     cellMatch = false;
     return false;
    }
   });
   if(cellMatch) {
       rowMatch = true;
       return false;
   }
  });
  if(!rowMatch) { 
   // r1 does not exist in t2, so we need to add it
   out.defaultValue.push(r2);
  }
 });
 log(JSON.stringify(out));

});

function log() {
 var s = '';
 $.each(arguments, function() {
  s += " " + this;
 });
 $('#out').append(s+"<br>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=out></div>
```